# Analytical methods for solving differential equations

Tags: numerical-methods, differential

For any continuous algebraic function we can estimate their roots by not using algebra but by analytical methods(e.g Newton-Raphson).Can we do the same for differential functions?

Comment: You call that "analytical"?

Comment: @MissMulan look for "Euler's method", "Crank-Nicolson's method", "Runge Kutta method", ...